# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngx-phone-select

Tags: angular, phone-number

i'm using ngx-phone-select for phone number field but getting issue 
**There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngx-phone-select"**
http://prntscr.com/hzbhfo

in angular 4.3 with ngx-phone-select 1.0.4 version

I've followed all the steps according to given document

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-phone-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per document I've added ngx-phone-select library in AppModule. and try to access the ngx-phone-select directive in child component.

so the solution is just add ngx-phone-select library in your child component to access directive of module